# update таблицы на основе join

Tags: sql, update, join, ssis

запутался сильно/ туплю) не могу обновить итоговую табл S из промежуточной U

1) пакет в SSIS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) INC Load выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) OLE DB distination (Updated Rows): все успешно добавляется  в промежуточную таблицу U при изменении данных в таблице (update id territory) 
U :
имеет такую же  структуру что и S.

```
  CREATE TABLE stg.tmpUpdateSalesOrderHeader AS U
  (
  SalesOrderID INT NULL,
  OrderDate DATETIME NULL,
  SalesOrderNumber NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
  CustomerID INT NULL,
  SalesPersonID INT NULL,
  TerritoryID INT NULL,
  SubTotal DECIMAL(16,6) NULL,
  TaxAmt DECIMAL(16,6) NULL,
  Freight DECIMAL(16,6) NULL
  );
```

4)  Execute SQL Task Update data имеет код

```
    UPDATE S
    SET
    OrderDate = U.OrderDate,
    SalesOrderNumber = U.SalesOrderNumber,
    CustomerID = U.CustomerID,
    SalesPersonID = U.SalesPersonID,
    TerritoryID = U.TerritoryID,
    SubTotal = U.SubTotal,
    TaxAmt = U.TaxAmt,
    Freight = U.Freight
    FROM stg.SalesOrderHeader AS S
    INNER JOIN stg.tmpUpdateSalesOrderHeader AS U ON S.SalesOrderID =
    U.SalesOrderID
```

5) Проблема:
При обновлении данных источника CDC:

```
   UPDATE источник CDC
   SET TerritoryID = 4
   WHERE SalesOrderID = 43659;
```

таблица U (промежуточная) обновляется : как итог
U: содержит 4 строки с одинаковым SalesOrderID но разным TerritoiryID (6,7,8,4),
но S никак не меняется 
S: содержит 3 строки полностью идентичных TerritoiryID (6,6,6)

в Чем проблема? помогите,  плиз. расписал подробно. почему он не апгрейдит итоговую таблицу ( Execute SQL Task update data)  - не меняет territory ID?

p.s.
после обновления territoryID
структура таблицы stg.SalesOrderHeader (нет territory ID 4)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

структура таблицы stg.tmpUpdateSalesOrderHeader (есть territory ID 4 как и прошлые изменения )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) Вместо вербального описания покажите CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO для таблиц. 2) Укажите используемую СУБД (вероятно, MS SQL Server?), включая версию.

Comment: Это Вы о чём? показывайте DDL таблиц и скрипты наполнения (добавьте их в текст вопроса, ссылка "править" под ним), а не референсы на таблицу в тексте запроса (их мы худо-бедно и сами разглядели).

Comment: правил долго)). добавил

Comment: 1) "пакет в SSIS" и "INC Load" - не нужны. 2) Нет DDL для SalesOrderHeader. 3) Нет примера исходных данных (наполнения обеих таблиц, в формате INSERT INTO), и требуемого результата для ИМЕННО ЭТОГО наполнения.

Comment: 1) обучение)  
2) имеете ввиду stg.SalesOrderHeader?
3) stg.SalesOrderHeader таблица с такими же столбцами что и stg.tmpUpdateSalesOrderHeader.  добавил структуру вопрос (в ps)/
требуемый результат: 
после изменения terittoryID на 4 . данные из промеж. таблицы stg.tmpUpdateSalesOrderHeader должны попасть в  stg.SalesOrderHeader ( по SalesOrderID). то есть изменения в territoryID.

Comment: 1) При чём тут обучение? эти данные НЕ НУЖНЫ в вопросе - просто удалите их. 2) Да, именно её. 3) Не вижу. Добавьте. Только возьмите структуру с сервера, а не копируйте - скорее всего, там обнаружатся "неучтённые" индексы. 4) Уберите фотографии, но добавьте скрипты наполнения таблиц тестовыми данными, чтобы можно было воспроизвести процесс обновления. И добавьте требуемый результат на ЭТИХ тестовых данных.

Comment: PS. Разглядывая фотографии. Я верно понимаю. что Вы желаете путём обновления из ОДНОЙ записи в основной таблице (у которой SalesOrderID = 43659) и ЧЕТЫРЁХ записей в таблице обновления (с тем же SalesOrderID и разными territoryID) получить в итоге ЧЕТЫРЕ записи в основной таблице? Огорчу - запрос на обновление в принципе неспособен изменить количество записей обновляемой таблицы.

Comment: нет, я хочу чтобы в таблице stg.SalesOrderHeader (с NULLами) обновилась запись  (у которой SalesOrderID = 43659) territory ID 6 на 4. Execute SQL Task Update  это должен делать, но не делает

Comment: *я хочу чтобы в таблице stg.SalesOrderHeader (с NULLами) обновилась запись (у которой SalesOrderID = 43659) territory ID 6 на 4* Почему именно на 4? почему не 6, не 7 и не 8?

Comment: потому что, таблица stg.tmpUpdateSalesOrderHeader хранит промежуточные результаты . в п.5) вопроса я писал, что  ранее я обновлял ID на 7, потом на 8, в самом конце на 4 - по шагово в SSMS/ таблица stg.tmpUpdateSalesOrderHeader все результаты складирует.
НО,  при запуске пакета, ни 7 , потом ни 8 , ни 4 ,я не увидел в итоговой таблице stg.SalesOrderHeader .